# Typing objects with default properties using Flow

Tags: flowtype

I am a bit confused about how to type objects with default properties using Flow.

For example, I have a function that takes an object with default properties, like so:

```
function load({ p = 1, pp = 5 }: Payload) {
  return {
    p,
    pp
  };
}
```

If I define the type of Payload like so:

```
type Payload = {
  p: ?number,
  pp: ?number
}
```

Flow will complain (apparently, because the fields of the object are no longer nullable). See example on [Try Flow](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBACghiANgezgEygXigbwFBRRgBcUA-AHYCuAtgEYQBOANAUSedfU3gL554AZlQoBjYAEtkFKCnQAKHESxQAjM3YqArFF6l4SVGgCUuNowjAqjGfkKEwre+za8A3HyA)

If I redefine Payload so that its fields are no longer nullable, Flow will be happy; but that of course will make it impossible to actually use default properties, as in the sample below:

```
type Payload = {
  p: number,
  pp: number
}

function load({ p = 1, pp = 5 }: Payload) {
  return {
    p,
    pp
  };
}

function test() {
  let p = null;
  let pp = 5
  load({p, pp}) 
}
```

example on [Try Flow](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBACghiANgezgEygXigbwFBRRgBcUAdgK4C2ARhAE4A0BRJ51d9eAvnngGYUyAY2ABLZGSgp0AChxEsUAIyNWSgKxRupeElRoAlLhb0IwCvSn5ChMM1usW3ANw8+gkeMlRgEAM7AssY20uaK2JSIiG6EiOFgYJosMmjy9qzcxjxAA)

What would be the proper way of using default object properties with Flow?

Comment: Unfortunately, this seems to be a bug with Flow. There's an [open issue](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/183) about it here.

Answer (score 0):

This does look like a bug. And it seems to be a bug related to treatment of `null`. I notice that if you limit the type union for `p` and `pp` to `number | void` (where `void` is the type for `undefined`) then your code works:

```
type Payload = {
  p: number | void,
  pp: number | void
}

function load({ p = 1, pp = 5 }: Payload) {
  return {
    p,
    pp
  };
}

function test() {
  let p /* undefined */
  let pp = 5
  load({p, pp}) 
}
```

But if you use the union `number | null` or `number | null | void` (which is the expanded form of `?number`) then you get the same error.

My guess is that has something to do with the way that default values work in Javascript. If the property has the value `undefined` then the default value is used. But the **the default value is not used if the property value is `null`**. So you probably do not want to allow `null` values anyway.